# Help naming a piece

Tags: furniture, metal, railing

I'm sorry for being vague and not using the right words, that's the actual issue, not knowing the right words. In the process of building a simple adjustable height shelf inside a box using four *insert name of item here* tracks that fix the movement up/down and have little steps inside so that if I stop going up, the shelf or whatever is attached to the track, doesn't go down.

Then there's either a release clip, or simply moving the shelf all the way up releases the stepper which allows you to go down until you start going up again.

I know, I'm sorry, I'd love to use the right words..
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The ratchet jack shelf support mechanism that you propose to use is a total pain to operate when there are four of them that all need to coordinate with each other.

You would be far better off to use this type of shelf support mechanism. Easy to adjust and very strong. The vertical rails (standards) can be mounted on surface as shown or embedded in a slot like you show in your drawing.

[image]

Comment: You reckon it would be a pain because some sides will go higher than another and it'll be hard to align properly? I would mostly be using it on two/three positions so the others would be sealed to prevent the bit from locking in, does that make sense?

Comment: @JuanCortés the alignment is pretty easy the slots are numbered. when cutting, make sure the cut is at the same number at the bottom on all pieces at set on the cabinet base.

Answer (score 1):

A search for cabinet shelve hardware, show "shelf standards" as the part your looking for. Make sure that the clips you order are for the standards you buy.

Comment: thanks for your time, the shelf standard does get me closer to what I'm looking for but would require for me to remove the shelf in order to adjust the height. What I'm after is the one where you can go higher by simply lifting the shelf, then at the top you can go lower

Answer (score 1):

There is a type of shelf standard that fits into a 5/8" wide by 3/16 deep groove by KV that will have the slots and clips to get the adjustability you need. They are typically nailed in, but in your case you may want to use 5/8"X 4 Ga screws.

[image]

They can be surface mounted or inset like you suggest. Also available in colors

Here is a copy and paste from

http://www.woodworkerexpress.com/Knape-and-Vogt-KV-255-ZC-72-72-255-Series-Pilaster/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cse&utm_campaign=google_product_ads&source=googlebase&gclid=CjwKEAiA6rrBBRDsrLGM4uTPkWASJADnWZQ4uYeEqPzmmmAQIvitYD_DpMEQ94TM-cWPrN5GNSiW-hoCMEjw_wcB

KV Model: KV255
Dimensions: 5/8" wide x 3/16" deep
Material: Steel standards: 23-gauge high strength steel. Aluminum standards: 17-gauge aluminum
Features: BHMA Grade 1 compliant. Slots for supports are adjustable in 1/2" increments. Stamped numbers make installation easier. Pre-drilled screw/nail holes 6" apart on center
Made in USA

Comment: Sorry Jack. Not trying to steal your answer. I had started to prepare my answer about 10 hours ago but was delayed by difficulty with trying to transfer my photo from phone to computer. Then I saw your answer!

Comment: @MichaelKaras Don't sweat it. I have done that too many times as well. As you may have noticed my answers get a little long winded. So by the time I get done and click it, another shorter, good answer get in there too.Your pic really illustrates the answer well.

Comment: Glad you liked the picture. Took that looking into a storage cabinet I built some 15 years ago.